# Ajax error message only show status

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, error-handling

I have a ASP.NET MVC website.

I have a Ajax request and I want to display a custom error if something goes wrong.

In my controller :

```
catch (Exception e)
  {
      Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
      Response.Write(e.Message);
      return null;
  }
```

in the Javascript :

```
error: function (xhr) {
    $("#ErrorDetails").html(xhr.responseText);
}
```

I don't know if this is a good way, but when I try it locally in debug, I get the full error message.

But if I host the website, I only get "Bad Request" instead of the message.

Any idea why and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it'll work in your scenario, but try adding the following to your **web.config** file under `<system.web>`:

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
  ...
</system.web>
```

By default the customErrors mode is set to **RemoteOnly** which means that local callers receive complete exception information; remote callers receive filtered exception information.

See more [under this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y123fsf7(v=vs.100).Aspx)

Comment: thanks for the tip, but it didnt work. I finally manage the error in the success callback instead of the error calback...

Answer (score 0):

I tried following javascript ajax (jQuery)code and able to get the error message.

```
 jQuery(function ($) { 
        $.ajax({ 
            url: "/Home/GetData", 
            type: "GET", 
            dataType: "text", 
            success: function () { 
                alert("Success"); 
            }, 
            error: function (xhr) { 
               alert(xhr.responseText); 
            } 
        }); 
    });
```

After hosting the website you need to update the url in your code. Can you verify if it is correct?

Comment: Yes I did that, the Url is automatically generated by "@Url.Action( "Action" , "Controller")" but I don't know why I only get "Bad Request" instead of the full error